# Storyboard localization swift at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, localization, storyboard

I had google many posts regarding the localization on IOS app. However, most of them are talking about objective-C and they do not mention on swift language. I just wonder that is it possible to use built in locatization feature in Xcode when changing storyboard at runtime. Please see the example as link below. Thank you.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fw3cyu&s=8#.VcBAIniloRl

Answer (score 2):

You Have to Write Custom Localisation methods, else in iPhone you can only change from **system setting**, which definitely makes device **reboot**, Here i have created a Custom Module of **In-app-localisation** in **SWIFT** from which it is possible to change language of your app in **runtime**

https://github.com/pr0gramm3r8hai/InAppLocalize

Comment: Dip - Thank you for your quick response and provide a solution to me. However, I would like to use main.strings file rather than build it by ourselves. Thank you.

Comment: Wc man ! i too tried lot to solve this issue, and reached up to that much, you are welcome to improve, :)

Comment: Dip - I would like to share something that I tested already. I had used the code as below can call the new storyboard with different language. However, this is not reload storyboard.

        var b : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: NSBundle(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("en", ofType: "lproj")!))
        var r : UIViewController =    b.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
        self.presentViewController(r, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Dip - After the paste the code below, I can reload the storyboard by using the main.strings language file. However, other resource file such as image can be be located.


var b : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: NSBundle(path: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("zh-Hant", ofType: "lproj")!))
        
        var r : UIViewController =    b.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
        
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController=r

Comment: yes ! But i think instantiating another story board with complete another design might not be the right solution ! in case of image this is the technique that should be used! but in case of localisation of story board we use the same story board but the string is used from localised string file  ! BTW thnks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to localize the label of storyboard programmatically, you can simply subclass the UILabel and translated it after you set text. So you do not need to create another storyboard.

```
class TranslatedLabel: UILabel {

    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        self.text = Language.sharedInstance.stringforKey(self.text!)
        super.drawTextInRect(rect)
    } 
}

class Language {
    class var sharedInstance : Language {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0
            static var instance : Language? = nil
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            Static.instance = Language()
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    func stringforKey(key:String)->String{
        let lan:String =     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("language") as! String
        let string:String?
        if lan.containsString("Hans"){
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("zh-Hans", ofType: "lproj")
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
            string = bundle?.localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: nil)
        }else if lan.containsString("Hant"){
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("zh-Hant", ofType: "lproj")
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
            string = bundle?.localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: nil)
        }else{
            let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("en", ofType: "lproj")
            let bundle = NSBundle(path: path!)
            string = bundle?.localizedStringForKey(key, value: nil, table: nil)
        }

        return string!
    }
}
```